# Is map of Future lazy or not?

Tags: scala, future

Basically I mean:

```
for(v <- Future(long time operation)) yield v*someOtherValue
```

This expression returns another `Future`, but the question is, is the `v*someOhterValue` operation lazy or not? Will this expression block on getting the value of `Future(long time operation)`?

Or it is like a chain of callbacks?

Comment: for comprehension is a collection of withFilter, map, and flatMap. And all this operations on a future return an future. So they are not blocking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A short experiment can test this question.

```
import concurrent._;
import concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object TheFuture {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val fut = for (v <- Future { Thread.sleep(2000) ; 10 }) yield v * 10;
    println("For loop is finished...")
    println(Await.ready(fut, Duration.Inf).value.get);
  }

}
```

If we run this, we see `For loop is finished...` almost immediately, and then two seconds later, we see the result. So the act of performing `map` or similar operations on a future is not blocking.

Comment: Yeah suddenly I find it doesn't matter at all. Even it is blocking, it is blocking in another thread. For example, `Thread.sleep(2000)` happens in childThread1, and in childThread2, `v * 10` is blocking on it. But it still won't affect mainThread. So based on this, I have another question, will childThread2 block by childThread1? Or the task will only start until childThread1 finish? Maybe I don't express well but I think you understand what I mean. Basically is: Will childThread2 block 2 seconds on waiting childThread1?

Comment: @Sraw no, it won't need to wait for the first thread to finish, unless you only have one thread left in your threadpool. Otherwise Silvio's example would cause deadlock. That's why you should never use `await` when the parent thread is also in the threadpool used by futures.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon So you mean it will block 2 secs right?

Comment: @Sraw If you mean "will Thread.sleep block the second thread," then yes. But neither thread will block the other unless you run into the deadlock issue I mentioned.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Thank you, I will do some tests on it.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon I use VisualVM to do the tests and find the second thread isn't even created until the first task finishes. So it seems it works just like a chain of callbacks. It won't really block 2 secs.

Answer (score 2):

A map (or, equivalently, your for comprehension) on a Future is *not* lazy: it will be executed as soon as possible on another thread. However, since it runs on another thread, it isn't blocking, either.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the definition and execution of the Future separately, then you have to use something like a `Monix Task`.

https://monix.io/api/3.0/monix/eval/Task.html